# runtimeerror size mismatch at tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

error message: RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [64 x 3200], m2: [512 x 1] at C:/w/1/s/windows/pytorch/aten/src\THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:290

The code is the following.:

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Generator, self).__init__()

    self.label_emb = nn.Embedding(opt.n_classes, opt.latent_dim)

    self.init_size = opt.img_size // 4  # Initial size before upsampling
    self.l1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(opt.latent_dim, 128 * self.init_size ** 2))

    self.conv_blocks = nn.Sequential(
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
        nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2),
        nn.Conv2d(128, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128, 0.8),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2),
        nn.Conv2d(128, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64, 0.8),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(64, opt.channels, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.Tanh(),
    )

def forward(self, noise, labels):
    gen_input = torch.mul(self.label_emb(labels), noise)
    out = self.l1(gen_input)
    out = out.view(out.shape[0], 128, self.init_size, self.init_size)
    img = self.conv_blocks(out)
    return img


class Discriminator(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Discriminator, self).__init__()

    def discriminator_block(in_filters, out_filters, bn=True):
        """Returns layers of each discriminator block"""
        block = [nn.Conv2d(in_filters, out_filters, 3, 2, 1), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True), nn.Dropout2d(0.25)]
        if bn:
            block.append(nn.BatchNorm2d(out_filters, 0.8))
        return block

    self.conv_blocks = nn.Sequential(
        *discriminator_block(opt.channels, 16, bn=False),
        *discriminator_block(16, 32),
        *discriminator_block(32, 64),
        *discriminator_block(64, 128),
    )

    # The height and width of downsampled image
    ds_size = opt.img_size // 2 ** 4

    # Output layers
    self.adv_layer = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(128 * ds_size ** 2, 1), nn.Sigmoid())
    self.aux_layer = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(128 * ds_size ** 2, opt.n_classes), nn.Softmax())

def forward(self, img):
    out = self.conv_blocks(img)
    out = out.view(out.shape[0], -1)
    validity = self.adv_layer(out)
    label = self.aux_layer(out)

    return validity, label


# Loss functions
adversarial_loss = torch.nn.BCELoss()
auxiliary_loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Initialize generator and discriminator
generator = Generator()
discriminator = Discriminator()

os.makedirs("../../data/mnist", exist_ok=True)
labels_path = 'C:/project/PyTorch-GAN/ulna/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'
images_path = 'C:/project/PyTorch-GAN/ulna/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
label_name = []

with gzip.open(labels_path, 'rb') as lbpath:
labels = np.frombuffer(lbpath.read(), dtype="int32", offset=8)
with gzip.open(images_path, 'rb') as imgpath:
images = np.frombuffer(imgpath.read(), dtype="int32", offset=16).reshape(len(labels),70,70,1)

hand_transform2 = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((70, 70)),
            transforms.Grayscale(1),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize([0.5], [0.5])
            ])

#images=cv2.resize(images, (70, 70),1)
dataset1 = datasets.ImageFolder('C:/project/PyTorch-GAN/ulna/ulna', transform=hand_transform2)


dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
dataset1,
batch_size=opt.batch_size,
shuffle=True,
)
```

The Traceback is the following.:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "acgan.py", line 225, in <module>
real_pred, real_aux = discriminator(real_imgs)
File "C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 541, in __call__
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "acgan.py", line 110, in forward
validity = self.adv_layer(out)
File "C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 541, in __call__
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 92, in forward
input = module(input)
File "C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 541, in __call__
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 87, in forward
return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
File "C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1370, in linear
ret = torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [64 x 3200], m2: [512 x 1] at C:/w/1/s/windows/pytorch/aten/src\THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:290
```

What I want to practice is the GAN code. The entire GAN code before modification can be found at the following link: https://github.com/eriklindernoren/PyTorch-GAN/blob/master/implementations/acgan/acgan.py
Input image is an x-ray image adjusted to 70x70, and output image is a fake x-ray image that is newly created by learning input x-ray image. The code worked well when practised with the minist database. I'm afraid I don't have a clue about the problem of code.
please help me! Thank you.

Comment: Please, add the full Traceback. The problem is probably because you changed the input size and something in your model is hard-coded, but you didn't share the code of the model.

Comment: I added! Thank you.

Comment: The traceback is still missing.

Comment: sorry, i added. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `opt.img_size` might still be set to 32 as if you were using CIFAR. As you resize it to 70, it should be set to 70.

Anyway, another problem will arise because `ds_size = opt.img_size // 2 ** 4` is not valid for `opt.img_size=70`. If you want a hard-coded solution, set `ds_size=5`. This fixes the Discriminator, but the same thing will happen to the Generator.

If you don't understand how to fix this properly, I would recommend you to take some time to read about how these models work. If you want to use the code as is, I would recommend you to use an `img_size` that is multiple of 16, e.g., `opt.img_size=80` and you would have no problem. To avoid other problems, you may want to use `transforms.Resize((opt.img_size, opt.img_size))` instead of hard-coding the `img_size` there.

Comment: I modified code. However, the error remains. RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [64 x 3200], m2: [2048 x 1] at C:/w/1/s/windows/pytorch/aten/src\THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:290

Comment: @dayday The problem is that by using 70, the computation `ds_size = opt.img_size // 2 ** 4` is not correct anymore.

Comment: @dayday I added an easy workaround, otherwise many other problems will appear because you are not using a multiple of 16 (i.e., 70).

Comment: @dayday :) if this answer helped you, consider marking as answer or upvoting it